# How can I check in C# in the easiest way whether a variable is equal to one of the elements of a list? I want to do that without a long OR expression

Tags: c#, list, logical-or

I have a variable named as "Input". This variable is the value of an input field. On the other side I have a List containing lot of strings

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Franz","Hans","Frank","Holger","Reiner".... };
```

I want to check whether the Operator's Input value is equal to one of the elements of my list.
Normaly I would write a very long logical or expression like

```
If(Input=="Franz" || Input=="Hans" || Input=="Frank" ... ) // hundreds of or's..
{
  DoSomething();
}
```

Isn't there an easier way to check whether the "Input" variable's value is equal to one of the List's elements, without using logical OR expression ?

Comment: May be you can use for or foreach cycle by names array and compare with each element

Comment: `names.Contains(Input)` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
if (names.Contains(Input))
{
  DoSomething();
}
```

This compares the items for a case-sensitve match. If you want to neglect differences in letter-casing, use

```
if (names.Any(x => Input.Equals(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
  DoSomething();
}
```

You could optimize upper sample by storing the names as lowercase in the list directly.

Comment: No need for `ToLower`, you can use `String.Equals` with `StringComparison.xxxIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ like so

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Franz","Hans","Frank","Holger","Reiner"};        
if(names.Any(name => String.Equals(name, input)))
    Console.WriteLine("input is in list");
else
    Console.WriteLine("input is not in list");
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnEjsg) for your convenience

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this just once, you can use `names.Contains(Input)` or `names.Any(name=>name.Equals(Input,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. This is an expensive operation though, because it has to check *all* values every time looking for a match.

If you have to do this multiple times, it's better to load the strings into a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0) or `Dictionary<string,...>. You can specify case-invariant matching by passing a [case-invariant comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=net-6.0) to the collection's constructor:

```
_nameSet=new HashSet<string>(names,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

....
if (_nameSet.Contains(Input))
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great way to do that by:

```
bool b = listOfStrings.Any(s=>myString.Contains(s));
```

using LINQ, which can be easily added.

So, then:

```
if(names.Any(s => s.Contains(Input))
{
  DoSomething();
}
```